# Using Viewboxes in wpf

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I was looking for a way to scale part of a wpf form properly when I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900859/tips-for-creating-scalable-wpf-user-control) on SO.  It actually told me quickly and succinctly what I needed to know but got me to wondering on the following question.

I have identified a need for a control with a particular degree of functionality and as such it's a perfect candidate for a user control.  One thing that it will need to be is scalable.  If I were to enclose the contents of my user control in a viewbox (and there were several of those controls on a form in a wpf application) would they conflict with any viewbox that might be wrapping all of the controls on a form?  In other words when designing user controls that require a degree of scalability is it acceptable to just 'wrap' the contents of the user control in a viewbox?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `Viewbox` will ["stretch/scale a single child element to the fill the available space"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You shouldn't run into any issues with `Viewboxes` at various nested levels composing a larger control (and it's fairly easy to test some general layouts in a mock project).

What is worth considering, is if the simple `Viewbox` scaling behaviour is actually what you're after. If you wanted say, a particular button to increase in size, or certain elements to stretch horizontally, you may get more mileage from various `Grid` layout options, with relative / proportional sizing/stretching.

Of course, the `Viewbox` scaling may be exactly what you're after =D

Comment: Thank you Chris.  As wpf and especially the nuances of xaml is still relatively new to me I've been having trouble setting up grids to provide the degree of relative scaling to which you allude.  The viewbox seemed to provide a simple 'easy' option.  Experimentation since posting my question suggests that perhaps I need to explore the inner workings of the grid in more detail....just need to find a good article on it  guess.

Comment: I found this site helpful for some quick examples/concepts: http://www.wpftutorial.net/Layout.html - which has an indirect link to a good MSDN page on the topic: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514519%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, potentially helpful.